# Join 2 Tables if Value of Foo.Column1 = x and Bar.Columns1 = y

Tags: sql, select, join

how can I make a join on columns that will never have equal values?

Is there a way I Left join 2 tables on [Foo.Column1 = x,y, or z] AND [Bar.Column1 = Q]

I want data in a query from 2 tables that have no equal values but I know that if a value in the first table is any one of 3 different values that it actually is equal to.

So can I join 2 tables where if Foo.Column1 contains a specified value and Bar.Column1 Contains a seperate special value then tell the statement the 2 rows are to be linked =?

No values are in either table the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a mapping relation between the values in the two tables like this:

```
select *
from Foo
join ( 
  select * from ( values 
    ('A', 'Z'),
    ('B', 'Z'),
    ('C', 'Z'),
  ) MapTable(FooColumn,BarColumn)
) MapTable on MapTable.FooColumn = Foo.Column1
join Bar on Bar.Column1 = MapTable.BarColumn
```

If the number of rows in MapTable is small and static you might even hardcode them by making MapTable a subquery.

Comment: So first design a MapTable in the database? I was hoping to skip this.

Comment: But how else ere you going to join two tables with no common field? Not my final commetn, about hard-coding it as a sub-query if it is small and static.

Comment: That was the reason for the question. If I could tell SQL that Values A,B, and C from this table is equal to value X of this table. Maybe something like query table 1 get all value for rows containing A,B, or C. then in a temp table replace all those values with the value I want them to equal to from table 2?

Comment: Check update; this is in the query, so could be used as dynamic SQL